# Two ways of movement for the same lumbar region

Tags: rigging, constraints, rigify

I reworked the Lumbar Region of the spine to let it move like in the first .gif[image]

In addition to that I wanted to add the regular movement which comes along with the non-modified rigify rig with the rig type "spine_super.spine". In order to get a more realistic behavior of the spine I needed both ways of movement.
So I added a few additional tweaks and MHC bones to be able to get the regular movement back to the lumbar region as you can see in the second .gif: https://giphy.com/gifs/XnPodlTW1GxgyAUtVk
As you can see the "new" movement of this twerk'ish movement works out when I start rotating its belonging bone. If I want to rotate the lumbar region like in the first .gif the region isn't affected by rotating.
I'm not sure which constraints have to be applied on which position to allow both ways of movement.
As far as I know the order which bones effects which are DEF > ORG > Tweak > MHC. As I said I added Tweak and MHC bones and Constraints to ORG which are applied to the new Tweak bones which affect the new MHC bones.

Comment: Just to let you know the second gif use corrupted link ...

Comment: Huh? For me it works, maybe because im logged in? not sure. Its supposed to be as a link because it's 2.98 mb and stackexchange allows uploads only up to 2mb